# My tensorflow custom loss function does NOT work. What's wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to get the loss function code workable. Looks like my code has problem at loop in batch that my loss fuction cannot get tensor's shape.
My code is

```
backbone = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=5, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(backbone.output)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=backbone.input, outputs=x)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    batch_loss = 0.0
    batch_cnt = len(y_true)
    for i in range(batch_cnt):
        tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(shape_invariants=[(batch_loss, tf.TensorShape([None]))])
        y_true_unit = y_true[i]
        y_pred_unit = y_pred[i]
        
        loss = 0.0
        for j in range(18):
            for k in range(32):
                conf_true = y_true_unit[j,k,0]
                cell_loss = tf.where(conf_true==1, 5 * tf.math.abs(y_true_unit - y_pred_unit), 0.5 * tf.math.abs(conf_true - y_pred_unit[j,k,0]))
                loss = tf.where(loss==0, tf.identity(cell_loss), tf.math.add(loss, cell_loss))
        batch_loss = tf.where(batch_loss==0, tf.identity(loss), tf.math.add(batch_loss, loss))
    return batch_loss / batch_cnt
sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(momentum=0.99)
model.compile(sgd, custom_loss)

reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=5)
model.fit(
    train_batch,
    validation_data = val_batch, 
    epochs = 100,
    callbacks = [reduce_lr]
)
```

and error is

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5952\2961884429.py", line 4, in yolo_loss  *
        for i in range(batch_cnt):

    ValueError: 'batch_loss' has shape () before the loop, which does not conform with the shape invariant (None,).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have complex logic inside a loss function, your loss function needs to be differentiable and `for loops` and `if` commands prevents this.

You need to write your loss function without `for` and `if` or it will never work.

To have an idea of the operations you can use and how to rewrite your loss function check out `Keras Backend`.

To give an idea: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-custom-loss-function-keras-3a89156ec69b

Comment: motivated yolo, I'd like to divide 2 ways to calculate loss. one is to get diff from all 5 channels when obj confidence =1, the other is to get diff from only first channel when obj confidence = 0. Can you help me, plz?

Comment: sorry but this sounds like the sort of things you can't do in a loss function :(, but i could be wrong, you need to write this things in a way that they are differentiable, to check all the operations possible you can go here https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~python/tf/keras/backend/mean

Answer (score 0):

Got solved the problem by below code, but I still don't know how it works well.

```
def yolo_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    batch_loss = 0.0
    count = len(y_true)
    for i in range(0, count):
        y_true_unit = tf.identity(y_true[i])
        y_pred_unit = tf.identity(y_pred[i])
        
        y_true_unit = tf.reshape(y_true_unit, [576, 5])
        y_pred_unit = tf.reshape(y_pred_unit, [576, 5])
        
        loss = 0
        for j in range(0,len(y_true_unit)):
            conf_true = tf.identity(y_true_unit[j,0])
            box_true = tf.identity(y_true_unit[j,1:])
            
            conf_pred = tf.identity(y_pred_unit[j,0])
            box_pred = tf.identity(y_pred_unit[j,1:])
            
            obj_exist = tf.ones_like(conf_true)
            if box_true[0] == 0.0 and box_true[1] == 0.0 and box_true[2] == 0.0 and box_true[3] == 0.0:
                obj_exist = tf.zeros_like(conf_true)
            
            conf_err = tf.math.pow(tf.math.subtract(conf_true, conf_pred), 2)
            local_err_x = tf.math.pow(tf.math.subtract(box_true[0], box_pred[0]), 2)
            local_err_y = tf.math.pow(tf.math.subtract(box_true[1], box_pred[1]), 2)
            local_err_w = tf.math.pow(tf.math.subtract(tf.sqrt(box_true[2]), tf.sqrt(box_pred[2])), 2)
            local_err_h = tf.math.pow(tf.math.subtract(tf.sqrt(box_true[3]), tf.sqrt(box_pred[3])), 2)
            
            if tf.math.is_nan(conf_err) == True:
                conf_err = tf.zeros_like(conf_err, dtype=tf.float32)
            if tf.math.is_nan(local_err_w) == True:
                local_err_w = tf.zeros_like(local_err_w, dtype=tf.float32)
            if tf.math.is_nan(local_err_h) == True:
                local_err_h = tf.zeros_like(local_err_h, dtype=tf.float32)
            
            local_err_coord = tf.math.add(local_err_x, local_err_y)
            local_err_shape = tf.math.add(local_err_w, local_err_h)
            local_err = tf.math.add(local_err_coord, local_err_shape)
            total_err = tf.math.add(conf_err, local_err)
            
            weighted_err = tf.math.multiply(total_err, 5.0)
            weighted_err = tf.math.multiply(weighted_err, obj_exist)
            
            if loss == 0:
                loss = tf.identity(weighted_err)
            else:
                loss = tf.math.add(loss, weighted_err)
        
        if batch_loss == 0:
            batch_loss = tf.identity(loss)
        else:
            batch_loss = tf.math.add(batch_loss, loss)
        
    return tf.math.divide(batch_loss, float(count))
```